# How can I change my location (country) on my psn account?

Tags: ps3

I want to change the psn location that was set when I created my account.

Comment: Unfortunately impossible. Many people are annoyed about this.

Comment: George T is right. For now there is no way to change the PSN location of an existing PSN Account

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, [changing PSN account location isn't allowed](https://www.playstation.com/en-ie/get-help/help-library/store---transactions/playstation-store-information---pre-orders/why-can_t-i-change-my-country-of-residence-/). This is due to anything from region-locked content to payment detail issues.

I don't expect this one to change anytime soon, if at all. Best chance you've got is to create a new account with a different location.